# Update !! Angular 10 : Injecting a service to a specific module , circular dependency detected. Difference between @inject and providers[ ]?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, service

I want to inject my service **countries.service** to my module **pricing.module** and use it in **list-pricing** component of that module.
I got **circular dependency detected** .
[image: This is my service]

**This is my module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PricingRoutingModule } from './pricing-routing.module';
import { DetailsPricingComponent } from './details-pricing/details-pricing.component';
import { ListPricingComponent } from './list-pricing/list-pricing.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [DetailsPricingComponent, ListPricingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PricingRoutingModule,
  
  ],
})
export class PricingModule { }
```

[image: This is my module]
**This is list-pricing a component from my module**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from 'src/app/Interfaces/post';
import { CountriesService } from 'src/app/services/countries.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-pricing',
  templateUrl: './list-pricing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-pricing.component.css'],
})
export class ListPricingComponent {
  result:Array<Post>;
  constructor(private service:CountriesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {  
     this.service.getCountries().subscribe(data=> 
        {  
     console.log("hello") 
          this.result=data;

      })    

 }
}
```

[image: This is list-pricing a component from my module]
**Pricing-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailsPricingComponent } from './details-pricing/details-pricing.component';
import { ListPricingComponent } from './list-pricing/list-pricing.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListPricingComponent },
  { path: 'detailsPricing', component: DetailsPricingComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PricingRoutingModule {}
```

[image]
**This is the error**
[image: This is the error]

**UPDATE !!**
It worked fine when I change the syntax from @Injectable({ provideIn:....}) in service , to providers [] in my module . I don't know what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Have you provided the CountriesService somewhere else already? Can you search for CountriesService across all your modules?

Comment: No I did not provide it somewhare else

Comment: @HassenBouzlima : Can you show whats in `price-routing.module.ts`? i get the feeling that there is something wrong in it . Would you mind creating a demo on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have added it , check it .

Comment: @HassenBouzlima : Ok, please try to share code rather than screenshot. I wont be putting much effort to write entire image code for an answer. PLease replace with actual code as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShashankVivek done check it out

Comment: @HassenBouzlima Please mark it as an answer if it helped

Comment: @HassenBouzlima sorry for going off-topic, but what is the plugin for drawing a line from one bracket to the matching one?

Comment: @frozenkoi it is Bracket Pair Colorizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually and 99% of the time providedIn value should be 'root', so that becomes tree shakable, it means if it is not used anywhere in app, it'll not be included in final compiled bundle.

Use below syntax, if it have application scope :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CountriesService {
}
```

For module scope, put it in providers array of module.

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  doSomething(): void {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [Service],
})
export class ServiceModule {
}
```

Replace your module and services name.

For component scope, put it in component metadata.

Helpful links : https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#creating-tree-shakable-providers

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I stumbled upon [this issue in Angular github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170) which talks about something similar. From what I understood, either use `providers:[CountriesService]` in `pricing.module.ts`

**OR**

create another module to break this circular dependency check which seems to be done Typescript compiler.

My suggestion is not to get into creating a new module but rather stick to the `providers` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
import {PricingModule} from '../pricing/pricing.module';
```

from countries.service .. which I suspect is causing the circular dependency.

Comment: Then how can I put PricingModule in @Injectable ({ProvidedIn: PricingModule }) ?

Comment: try to inject into root for test it out @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

Comment: great ! if you want to keep the service limited to the module then i think you need to specify the provider in your module file. see this https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: I think @injectable({providedIn:myModule}) in service replace provider in module .